# How can I assign array in a jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, console, jagged-arrays

I have 3 sets of array they are: a[i], b[j], c[k] and I have to assign them to a jagged array for me to show them to the output.

```
array[0] = new int[3] { a[i] };
array[1] = new int[2] { b[j] };
array[2] = new int[2] { c[k] ];

for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
     Console.Write("First Array: ");
     for (int l = 0; l < array[i].Length; l++)
     {
           Console.Write("\t" + array[i][l]);
     }

     Console.Write("Second Array: ");
     for (int m = 0; m < array[i].Length; m++)
     {
           Console.Write("\t" + array[i][m]);
     }

     Console.Write("Third Array: ");
     for (int n = 0; n < array[i].Length; n++)
     {
           Console.Write("\t" + array[i][n]);
     }

     Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But I couldn't make them work, they are always giving me an error.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Sweeper it says System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript similary thing can be done by-

```
let a =  [ '1','2','3']
let b =  ['4','5']
let c =  ['6','7']

let array = []
array.push(a)
array.push(b)
array.push(c)
console.log(array)
```

output

```
[ [ '1', '2', '3' ], [ '4', '5' ], [ '6', '7' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = new int[] { 4, 5 };
int[] c = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int[][] array = new int[][] { a, b, c };
```

Answer (score 0):

That should probably look more like:

```
// place references to the source arrays into the jagged array
array[0] = a[i];
array[1] = b[j];
array[2] = c[k];

// iterate over the jagged array and output each array that is within
for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Array " + i + ": ");
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("\t" + array[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Note that we only have ONE inner `for` loop that is iterating over each inner array using the outer loop's `i` variable.

Comment: I tried this but this is not working. Supposed the arrays a[i], b[j], and c[k] are all arrays base from the inputs of the user @Idle_Mind

Comment: Post more complete code. Show us how a, b, and c are created and populated. As it is, we can only guess what the problem might be.